# Cambiar elemento en una Application

Tags: android, activity

Estoy trabajando la libreria de altbeacon usando [beacons de fondo](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html#starting-an-app-in-the-background)
la uso para obtener eventos con firebase, cuando esta de fondo notifica los eventos que estén programadas el mismo día, cuando esta abierta muestra los eventos en un recycler view, necesito que cuando se salga de la region de los beacon cambie la pantalla de eventos, pero desde una clase que extiende de Application no puedo acceder a los elementos con  findViewById, intente con

```
 View v = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.activity_event_list,null);
```

dentro de didExitRegion pero cualquier cambio que haga con v.findViewById.set algo no funciona
tuve que crear un método estático en la Activity y usar un activity estático

```
private static Activity activity = null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    activity = this;
....
 public static void changeList() {
    if (activity==null){
        return;
    }

    RecyclerView rv = activity.findViewById(R.id.lista_eventos);
    if (rv != null) {
        if (NotificationService3.estado) {
            rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

entonces dentro del método didExitRegion y el onCreate de la Activity llamo la función estática,probé también con pasare al método un contex para cree la view con un inflate, por parámetro pero ya sea llamado en la activity o en la application no resulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola en lugar de usar metodos static te recomiendo que uses una interfaz.

Creas una interfaz para que con uno o dos metodos y haces que el Activity implemente la interfaz, luego le pasas esa interfaz al Application desde el Activity. Finalmente, cuando cae en didExitRegion llamas al metodo que necesites de esa interfaz.

Deberia quedar algo asi el Application:

```
public class MyApplication exteds Application {

   public RegionInterface mRegionInterface;

   @Override
   public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
      if (mRegionInterface!=null) mRegionInterface.regionChanged();
   }   

   public interface RegionInterface {
      void regionChanged();
   }
}
```

Y en el activity tendrias que poner esto:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implement RegionInterface {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();
      myApplication.mRegionInterface = this;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      //Super importante para que no explote
      MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();
      myApplication.mRegionInterface = null;
   }

   @Override
   public void regionChanged(){
      //Aca pones el codigo que necesites para cambiar las vistas del activity
   }  
}
```

Usando esto siempre podras tener una comunicacion entre el Application y el Activity sin problema, no solo para este caso puntual sino siempre que necesites pasar algun dato o atrapes algun evento.